# youtube javascript api doesn't trigger callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to work with youtube's javascript api and am having a problem initializing it/getting a callback when it's ready. Api documentation can be found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html).

I'm getting the videos from the json provided by youtube and embedding them like this:

```
//insert flash object in video element
        $(video_elm_arr[i]).append('<object id="video_' + i + '" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '">' + 
                                   '<param name="movie" value="' + video_url + '?showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1"></param>' +
                                   '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>' +
                                   '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>' +
                                   '<embed src="' + video_url + '?showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '"></embed>' +
                                   '</object>');
```

Note that I'm adding 'enablejsapi=1' to the url which should enable the javascript api. However, when I listen for the callback that the api is ready, ie:

```
//set player functionality when javascript api is available
  function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    alert('api is ready!');
  }
```

it never gets triggered. Everything else on the page (including the youtube videos) loads correctly, and even the other parameter I pass in the videos url (showinfo=0) works properly. What gives? Anyone see my error? All help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: I know youtube recommends 'swfObject', but it's not an option in my case...

Comment: I've found a way around this problem (just using the thumbnails is reasonable for what I need), but I'd still like to know the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the page being served from a server (ie, not from a local machine)? Youtube (or Flash in general) is not allowed to interact with JavaScript if the page is served locally.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `&playerapiid=THEPLAYERIDYOUWANTPASSEDIN` to the URL. This is sent to the callback as the "playerId" parameter.

```
//insert flash object in video element
        $(video_elm_arr[i]).append('<object id="video_' + i + '" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '">' + 
                                   '<param name="movie" value="' + video_url + '?showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=' + i + '"></param>' +
                                   '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>' +
                                   '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>' +
                                   '<embed src="' + video_url + '?showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '"></embed>' +
                                   '</object>');
```